# How do you get local time and do not update it when time changes?

Tags: android, android-studio, localtime

I have to get the Localtime of UTC+5:45. I found the code and implemented it but the time gets updated when the as time progresses. How to get it fixed without updating? 
This is the code that I have implemented:

```
  Date localTime = new Date();
  String format = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
  sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+5:45"));
  Date gmtTime = new Date(sdf.format(localTime));
  System.out.println("Local:" + localTime.toString() + "," + localTime.getTime() + " --> UTC time:"
            + gmtTime.toString() + "," + gmtTime.getTime());
  Date fromGmt = new Date(gmtTime.getTime() + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(localTime.getTime()));
  return String.valueOf(fromGmt);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit the question to include your relevant code, which will enable the community to help you. At the moment we have almost nothing to go on. Thanks.

Comment: I had added the code which I have implemented..please guide me @MandyShaw

Comment: I am not an Android person, I am just looking at posts from new contributors to check that enough info has been provided. You'll need to wait for an Android expert to pick this up.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. Especially when thing get just a little bit complex as in your question.

Answer (score 2):

When you use :

```
Date localTime = new Date();
```

You get the current time.
So every time you call new Date(); the time will be different.
You have to call new Date() only once and use that object for the rest of your code.
If you need 2 Date objects of different time zones, use:

```
Date localTime = new Date();
Date newDate = new Date(localTime.getTime());
```

This way you'll have the 2 times synced.

Date has no timezone so you have to specify a year a month and a day along with the time to make it specific.

Answer (score 0):

code snippet you offer make me think that it is a method which return formatted local time, be sure this method is called just once to get time. And if you are making an Android App you can use Log instead of System.out.println.

Answer (score 0):

```
   TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
                    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new 
                     SimpleDateFormat(pattern, new Locale("eng", "ind"));
                    String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
                    Log.i("get C_d_t", date);
```